# How to use Powershell code to loop through subdirectories and delete specific folders?

Tags: powershell

If I am in my current working directory, is there a powershell code that I can run which will loop through the subdirectories and delete all folders that are named 400eV, 410eV, 420eV... up to 500eV?

Specifically, I am in my current working directory. In this directory I have 24 folders, Angle1, Angle2, etc... up to Angle24

In each of these folders I want to delete 11 folders named 400eV, 410eV, etc. up to 500eV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont like too much the questions of type "give me the code" but here is a hint of what you can do:

```
$regularExpression = "(4[1-9][0-9]|500)eV$"
```

`ls -rec -direc | ? {$_.fullname -match $regularExpression} | % { rm $_.fullname -force -recu -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}`

EDIT:
if you have an old powershell

`ls -rec| ? {$_.PSIsContainer}  | ? {[Regex]::IsMatch($_.fullname, $regularExpression)} | % { rm $_.fullname -force -recu -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}`

Comment: Should the regular expression part contain all the names of the folders I want deleted?

Comment: No, the idea of a regular expression is to have a string that represent a set of strings in a very concise way. In this case you need [NumbersFrom400To500] concatenated with the string [eV], check this link for more info [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have modified the answer, there you have your regular expression. As a side note be careful with the `-force -recurse` parameters. If a folder name match the regular expression is going to delete recursively from that point onwards. Use it wisely.

Comment: When I run the command, it just brings up a >>

Comment: Careful with line breaks, there are two lines, one define the $regularExpression variable, and the other is one complete combined statement that do a lot of things. 2 lines, no more.

Comment: Should I put this all in a script? I was trying to run through commands in powershell

Comment: Even in a bat file It does not seem to run. maybe its just not compatible

Comment: bat is for cmd not powershell. Copy first line then enter, copy second line then enter, isn't that dificult. I think you should read some basics primer about powershell.

Comment: I mean I did that but if you read my initial question your command does not do what I asked. Instead of just deleting the folders I asked for, it deletes all folders. I need it to just delete specific folders throughout all the Angle Subfolders. I was hesistant to run the command exactly because I did not how it would not delete everything. I just ran it. And it deleted everything.

Comment: My mistake, the correct method is IsMatch not directly Match, I will update the answer, hopefully you had a backup

Comment: I updated my question to be clearer. Perhaps my initial statement was not that clear. Yes, I do have a backup. I would never run commands like this without having a backup

Comment: great, try again with the IsMatch fix

Comment: OK it seems to be working. Just 2 quick questions. Is there a way to make it go from 410 to 500 instead (realizing now I'd like to keep 400eV. Also, can this loop through each Angle directory and perform this command instead of having me go into each one and run it?

Comment: sure there is! change your regular expression `"^(4[1-9][0-9]|500)eV$"` . For the other thing just position one directory more near to the root, where the Angles folder exists  `cd..` . The code already does a recursive call so that is all you need

Comment: i tried doing cd .., but i just get path not found (pages of those errrors)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36707/discussion-between-mjsr-and-jackson-hart).

Comment: I tried going to the chat but I dont think you are there