# How to Delete Folders with Powershell using Remove-Item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to delete a lot of folders.
When I run the command:

```
Remove-Item -Filter *Angle* -WhatIf
```

I get the error:

> Supply values for the following parameters

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Powershell code to loop through subdirectories and delete specific folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/1049915/how-to-use-powershell-code-to-loop-through-subdirectories-and-delete-specific-fo)

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided the path\folder you want to remove.

For example:

> Remove-Item c:\myfolder -Filter Angle -WhatIf

Comment: When I run this: Remove-Item . -Filter Angle* -400eV -Recurse, I get teh error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accept the argurment -400eV

Comment: What exactly is "-400ev"

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a path to Remove-Item as well as the recurse switch to tell it to delete subfolders

> Remove-Item -Path C:\myproject\temp -Recurse

Comment: When I run this: Remove-Item . -Filter Angle* -400eV -Recurse, I get teh error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accept the argurment -400eV

Answer (score 0):

Two errors on your statement.

- You are not providing the path to delete
- Angle is nothing, provide a string in the form "stringValue" or trough a variable

For more information use `man remove-item`, `man about_parameters`